# need help connecting to bitbucket repository with sourceTree on windows 8

Tags: version-control, repository, bitbucket

I'm having trouble adding and cloning my repo on bitbucket to the sourceTree app, we're only starting with this now and we're a small company, so there's not much knowledge around this.

now I've gone through [The documentation on sourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sourcetree+Git+GUI+on+Windows?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#addcomment) for help, but I've noticed when I select my repo on bitbucket, it uses the repo url I select and appends a `.git` at the end. Then a notice message says `This is not a valid source path / URL`, but when I click `Details...` I get a dialogBox with nothing in it and an ok button. and when I'm done entering the details the 'Clone' button remains disabled.
Is this Windows 8 or am I actually doing something wrong?

Now I usually use ubuntu, but we just got these new ASUS ultrabooks at work and it's a pain to install any linux Distro on here. So I'm stuck with windows 8

Comment: SourceTree on Windows doesn't support Mercurial (hg), only git. Is your repo on Bitbucket a git or hg repo?

Comment: Hi Wilbert, sorry I am using git, turns out git was disabled, but it's working now thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out git AND mercurial are both disabled by default (idiots) so 
I clicked on `Tools > Options' and selected the git tab, you'll find it's disabled if you've just installed it, click the enable button.

and then to execute the shell commands given by the SourceTree documentation you can click the Terminal button in the main SourceTree interface